# Reducing a parsed boole grammar

Tags: regex, parsing, boolean, grammar

I've implemented a parser for conditional statements. The purpose of the complete program is finding values that match the condition. For example, in the sentence: "a>0 AND b==10", my program would suggest setting a=1 and b=10. Sometimes it can get trickier with more complex sentences like "a>0 AND a+b==10", for example, but I'm solving it for now.

My biggest concern is for those sentences that are formal fallacies, so they must be discarded for having no solution. For example, in the case of "a==0 AND a>0". This example is easy to handle, but if you consider nesting, like in "a==0 AND ((b>3 AND a==10) OR (b<2 AND a==10))".

I think I am able to translate as follows:

b>3 => P, b<2 => ¬P, a==0 => Q, a==10 => ¬Q

So the previous example would be: "Q AND ((P AND ¬Q) OR (¬P AND Q))".

Once I can get a sentence like that, the real question is: is there an algorithm or a way to reduce the sentence and directly knowing if it is an axiom or a fallacy? Or would it be the best way to create the full T/F chart and check if all results are False?

Comment: If you can indeed translate your statements in such a way, what you have is SAT, well known and extensively studied problem in computer science. I'm not entirely convinced you would be able to do that for every conditional statement, you are dealing with unrestricted sets after all.

Comment: That's a little problem, indeed. Most statements will be opposite, like `a<3` or `a>=3`. But in some cases I will have `a==0 or a==1 or a==2`. I hadn't thought of that depply, so i guess the translation is not a complete solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can use sets of intervals for each variables.

F.e. condition `b == 2 OR a > 4` gives union of intervals `b => [2]` and `a => (4, ∞)`.

`OR` operator gives the union of sets, f.e. `a < 5 OR a > 10` gives `(-∞, 5) ∪ (10, ∞)`; `AND` operator gives the intersection, f.e. `a > 5 AND a < 10` gives `(5, 10)`.

Now, having empty set at some stage of expression processing you can diagnose inconsistent conditions.

Comment: This seems a very good idea, but I wouldn't really know how to proceed in case a value is irrelevant. For example, in the condition `(a<2 OR b>2) AND (a<0 OR b<0)`b is an empty set, but the condition is only dependent of variable a. How could it be treaated?

Comment: Good question. As I see it, you may use naïve implementation of sets union/intersection. For your example we have `a => (-∞, 0) ∪ b => []` (empty set), so result is non-empty set. Of course, this operation should be evaluated at the end of processing only (not at each stage).

Comment: I think this might be getting over my capabilities, hahaha. I had never worked with that kind of sets, but they seem to cover almost all my needs. I will have a look at that. I won't be able to cover yet sentences like `a > 0 AND a + b = 10` but it's still a huge advance. Thanks for putting me in the right path.